# how to convert site minder xml configuration using Spring4 Java config

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-4, siteminder

I am converting an old version based Spring application to annotation based Spring4 application. As a first step I converted all xmls to java configuration based annotations. The application is working fine, but the only issue is with the site minder xml configuration. I don't know how to convert the below siteminder configuration which is there in the web.xml into java based.

```
<login-config>
   <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
   <realm-name>SiteMinderRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

The above siteminder configuration is in web.xml,

Can anyone please tell me how to write the java based configuration for the above xml in AppInitializer.java

my **web.xml** and its corresponding substituted **AppInitializer.java** code is as shown below

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>SpringWebMVCApp</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.helloworld.config.AppConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
        <realm-name>SiteMinderRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

**AppInitializer.java**

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/rest/");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class);
        return context;
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

```
public class AppInitializer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/rest/");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class);
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.httpBasic().realmName("SiteMinderRealm").and().x509();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have both a `web.xml` and a `WebApplicationInitializer`? Which aren't even the same?

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using only WebApplicationInitializer not web.xml, web.xml shown which is from my old spring application, which I am trying to convert to spring4 java config, Only thing is that I dont know how to convert those siteminder stuff to java config

Comment: For `login-config` there is no java equivalent, that is left out of the java servlet spec not sure why. You would need both a `web.xml` (for the `login-config`) and Java stuff you have for configuration Spring (Although I would suggest extending`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`).

Comment: What isn't clear about *there is no java equivalent*? So no there is no work around...

Comment: so we have to use only xml

Comment: No... As I mentioned use a `web.xml` for the `login-config` and there rest can be in java config. You can mix and match...

Comment: can we give some other name instead of web.xml and call within  java config

Comment: Obviously no as the name is dictated by the servlet spec.

Comment: :(................. then its better I can use xml rather than java config

Answer (score 5):

Did you try configuring this on the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`? Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.httpBasic().realmName("SiteMinderRealm").and().x509();
   }
}
```

Comment: do we not to mention `auth-method` in that

Comment: `x509()` is same as `<auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: can you take a look at my Update1 , that is how I have done

Comment: Did you make sure `configure(HttpSecurity http)` is getting called? Try to log a message in it and see if it's running on startup. If it doesn't run you might need `@Configuration` `@EnableWebSecurity` at the top of the class.

Comment: is my update1 correct, can we integrate this in AppInitializer

Comment: Security Config is usually a separate class from Initializer. I added annotations to my post.

Comment: still its not entering